# Not necessarily an IF function, but a condition being met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get a cell in Excel to display one cell's value for a value of less than 20, and display a different cell's value if its results are 20 and greater. What function or formula would I use?

I want cell `j23` to display value for cell `b23` if value is under 20, or if value is 20 and greater to display cell value `f23`.

Comment: Thankyou scott and forward. works now beautifully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) is made up of 3 parts

- Logical
- True result
- False result (optional)

=IF(Logical,True Result, False Result)

```
=IF(B23<20,B23,F23)
```

---

IF by the title of your question you are trying to AVOID the if statement you have a couple of options.  I must stress I am not a FAN of the VLOOKUP options and they are only presented as an option of not using IF.

You could make a little chart.

```
   A    |    B
  20    |  =F23

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B23,'somesheet'!$A$1:$B$1,2,1),B23)
```

Or you could go the indirect route using the following table:

```
=INDIRECT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B23,'somesheet'!$A$1:$B$1,2,1),"B23")

   A    |    B
  20    |  F23

'(the F23 is text)
```

---

My personal favourite of non if options:

```
=CHOOSE((B23<20)+1,J23,B23)
```

Comment: @ScottCraner Did I trim the fat on that answer enough? 8)  I have to keep myself balanced after my last Q.

Comment: Thats not quite working, comming up circular reference since i want this displayed in j23, and the answer juxtaposed b32 for b23.  The formula is pasting into j23.

Comment: nice and concise, but your dyslexia kicked in.

Comment: @DonaldLatta see edit.  The formula should work now.

Comment: @DonaldLatta if this works please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Comment: I was in the middle of verboseness answer to find a solution that did not use IF when you edited.  Cant believe I misread that question though.  I thought J23 was the criteria cell. and true was B23 and false was F23.

Comment: Absolutly beautiful. Thankyou a bunch everybody. @ scott craner

Comment: @ScottCraner  I could not stop myself with adding options!